# Search method with compare operators

Tags: c#, search

I want to write a dynamic search function that reads a string and splits it depends on some constants.

My sample code works only on the search string and not on the different variations of it.

```
        // String to clean
        searchString = "month == Jan || (name == “ni*” && age > 18)";

        const string ageStr = "age";
        const string monthStr = "month == ";
        const string nameStr = "name == ";
        const string startQutation = "“";
        const string endQutation = "”";
        const string star = "*";

        string month = searchString.Substring(searchString.IndexOf(monthStr) + 9, 3);
        searchString = searchString.Remove(searchString.IndexOf(monthStr), 12);

        string nameOrginal = searchString.Substring(searchString.IndexOf(startQutation) + 1, 
                                searchString.IndexOf(endQutation) - searchString.IndexOf("“") - 1);
        string name = nameOrginal;
        if (name.Contains("*"))
        {
            name = name.Remove(name.IndexOf(star), 1);
        }
        searchString = searchString.Remove(searchString.IndexOf(nameStr), 8 + nameOrginal.Length + 2);

        string ageCompare = searchString.Substring(searchString.IndexOf(ageStr) + 6, 2);
        ageCompare = ageCompare.Trim();
        string age = searchString.Substring(searchString.IndexOf(ageStr) + 8, 2);

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Name: {0}\nMonth: {1}\nAge:{2}\nAge compare operator:{3}",
                                             name, month, age, ageCompare));
```

The result is and should be:
    month = "jan"
    name = "ni"
    age = 18
    ageCompare = ">"

I need a better function that clears the string after the constants so it will not be wrong if the string is different than the hard-coded string.

Best regards

Comment: Can you give an example of a "different" string? I think it will help me to pinpoint the essence of your question.

Comment: Okey. Here is a string that doesn't work: "month == Jan || age > 18"

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I think it's hard to make it really "dynamic" this way. You are basically trying to write your own little compiler. Maybe you should consider to make it work, perhaps less dynamically, but more fail-safe. You can try to start with an other syntax and some constants. For example: an input as `12;34;ni;>` where 12 is the month, 34 is the age, ni the name and > the type of operation. You can split the input on the `;` mark. Make sure your `;` mark isn't allowed as input (or just pick another mark :))

Comment: Alternative; if you are using linq you can use Dynamic Linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx